# How to substring elements as 2 groups

Tags: c#, substring

I am trying to make a sqrt operation from scratch. I was able to extract two elements from a string, but I got stuck after that.

```cs
int number = 1234 , the_two_numbers;
string z = Convert.ToString(number);
int x = z.Length;
for(int i =0 ; i < x ; i++){
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    the_two_numers = Convert.toInt32(z.Substring(i , i+ 1));
  }
}
```

How do I get the value of `the_two_numbers` as `12 / 24`?

If I made any other mistakes on the way, please ignore them; I'm a newbie. The rest of my program is working well :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you help me understand the purpose of your code? Based on the code itself, I'm assuming that what you want is to extract even indexed digits—in this case, the `1` and `3`—and concatenate them into a new number stored  in `the_two_numbers` variable. That said, based on your explanation, it sounds like you _also_ want the _odd_ indexed numbers (in this case, `2` and `4`), stored as either another variable, or perhaps as an entry in an array? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to split this into two different numbers based on odd vs. even indices—i.e., `13` and `24` in your test value—there are three issues with your code:

1. You can only store one number in an `int`; you'll need an `int[]` to store two numbers;
2. You currently overwrite the previous value of the number, instead of concatenating it;
3. The second parameter of `Substring()` is the number of characters you want to pull after the start index, so it should be `1` not `i+1`.

To resolve these issues, you'd likely want something similar to:

```cs
var number            = 1234;
var the_two_numbers   = new int[2];
var z                 = Convert.ToString(number);

for (int i=0; i<z.Length; i++) 
{
  the_two_numbers[i%2] = Convert.ToInt32(the_two_numbers[i%2].ToString() + z.Substring(i, 1));
}
```

Note the following:

1. I made `the_two_numbers` an array instead of an `int`;
2. Instead of conditionally excluding odd indices, I instead use that to determine what index of `the_two_numbers` to write to (`[i%2]`); and
3. Instead of *just* setting the value at the current index to the variable, I concatenate it to any previous values.

With `the_two_numbers` established as an array, you can then retrieve the first value (`13`) using `the_two_numbers[0]`, and the second value (`24`) using `the_two_numbers[1]`.